# Google Maps. Traffic information at specified point

Tags: google-maps, traffic

Is there a way to determine what traffic condition is at specified concrete point or street? I figured out i could just "ask directions" and divide by length but it would be more convenient to have such stuff in the api, i.e., get the full list of streets where is currently a traffic jam in one city.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600656/traffic-data-from-google

Comment: http://www.quora.com/Is-there-any-public-API-for-obtaining-traffic-information

Answer (score 0):

I have been looking for those API's myself. Dont think they are available.