# How to enable traffic information along a specific route in Google Maps V2?

Tags: android, android-maps-v2

Google Navigation shows the traffic layer only for a given route. With `GoogleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true)` I'll get the traffic information for the whole map.

I know how to draw polylines for a route from Google Directions, but how can I turn on the traffic layer only for that route?

Comment: I am also face same problem..can you give updated answer for your question..see my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313161/find-the-traffic-between-two-locations-in-android

Comment: @ranjith I'm sorry to say, that I never solved this problem. It seems Google keeps some functionality for their own APIs. Also I haven't programming Android for quiet some time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not possible as of API v2 version 3.1.36. You may want to post a feature request on [gmaps-api-issues](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list?can=2&q=apitype=Android2).

Comment: No offense but where did you get this info?

Comment: @SteveBenett I seem to know the API fairly well. There is no function which lets you do that. `GoogleMap.setTrafficEnabled` is the only traffic-related API. The lecture doesn't take much time: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/

Answer (score -1):

The difference between these two values (duration and a duration in traffic) indicates how delayed your customer is going to be on their way to or from their location.

Reference: [Access Google's Traffic Data through a Web Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4600656/access-googles-traffic-data-through-a-web-service)

Discussion: http://searchengineland.com/pull-google-maps-traffic-data-into-adwords-with-this-script-library-248934