# How to get information along a specific route for google map android?

Tags: java, android, api, google-maps

With GoogleMap.setTrafficEnabled(true) I can get the traffic information for the whole map only.

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html#setTrafficEnabled(boolean)

I also know that it is impossible to get the information for the specific route via the official API from google map.

[How to enable traffic information along a specific route in Google Maps V2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16843264/how-to-enable-traffic-information-along-a-specific-route-in-google-maps-v2)

However, if I also wanna to do so, are there any others way to get the traffic information for specific route? Any stupid methods are also accepted.

For me, I just have a solution that using polyline function but I don't know how to extract information from google map.

Thanks all.

Comment: Finally, I find the solution. Thanks.

Comment: The difference between these two values (duration and a duration in traffic) indicates how delayed your customer is going to be on their way to or from their location.

Reference: Access Google's Traffic Data through a Web Service

Discussion: http://searchengineland.com/pull-google-maps-traffic-data-into-adwords-with-this-script-library-248934